# Wondering how to go about XOR'ing a single string of 8 bit binary in python - as in outputting every combination possible to get the single string

Tags: python, binary

I've seen multiple codes and ways to XOR two binary strings into one, but the question I have is how I'd go about XOR'ing a single byte to get every single possible XOR combination outputted.

Comment: What do you mean by "every single possible XOR combination"?

Comment: As in, if the binary were to be 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 - the outputs would be 1 0 or 0 1 for the first one and so one for every digit. Trying to get it to output every single combo as a binary 8 bit sequence - or in a format which I can read as a clear binary 8 bit sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Use nested loops that XOR every pair of byte values:

```
for x in range(256):
    for y in range(256):
        print(f"{x} XOR {y} = {x ^ y}")
```